# Как подключить свой шрифт через @font-face и другие способы?

Tags: css, шрифты

Просмотрел аналогичные вопросы и ни в одном не нашел ответа. Использовал разные форматы шрифтов такие как:
eot, woff, ttf, svg. Использовал несколько браузеров ни в одном не работает. Сначала использовал пре-процессор scss позже обычный css. пути к файлам проверил.
путь до шрифтов :C:\Users\user_1\Desktop\HTML\2 курс\№14(fonts)\fonts.
вот код на css:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
@import "../css/null.css";
@font-face {
  font-family: "Conv_big_noodle_titling";
  src: url("../fonts/big_noodle_titling.eot");
  src: local("☺"), url("../fonts/big_noodle_titling.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/big_noodle_titling.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/big_noodle_titling.svg") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

P.S в google fonts шрифта "BigNoodleTitling" нет.

Comment: раз весе нормально, то применяете то к обычному тексту, а не какому нить жирному или курсиву?

Comment: но я и так применяю к обычному  тексту.